# Using MUI filter on array object column

Tags: javascript, material-ui, datagrid

I am having issues customizing the filter of MUI data grid since one of my columns (which is the main column where I wanted my filtering be applied only) is consisted by array of object.

```html
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "origin": 1078,
        "destination": 472,
        "origin_service": 2905,
        "origin_transhipment_port": 826,
        "main_service": 1553,
        "main_transhipment_port": 1294,
        "destination_service": 45,
        "full_name": "THI6C to NGTIN via Dole: GULFPORT (NOAES) - ACL-Atlantic Container Line: V SERVICE (EGAIC) - ANL: ACSA5",
        "sellers": [
            1,
            3
        ],
        "sellers_data": [
            {
                "pk": 1,
                "name": "SlotsDemo"
            },
            {
                "pk": 3,
                "name": "sampleSeller"
            }
        ],
        "origin_data": {
            "pk": 1078,
            "unlocode": "THI6C",
            "name": "Bangkok (Old Port)",
            "slug": "bangkok-old-port1",
            "short_name": "",
            "country": "Thailand",
            "nearby": [],
            "tags": []
        },
        "destination_data": {
            "pk": 472,
            "unlocode": "NGTIN",
            "name": "Tincan",
            "slug": "tincan",
            "short_name": "",
            "country": "Nigeria",
            "nearby": [],
            "tags": []
        },
        "origin_service_data": {
            "pk": 2905,
            "name": "GULFPORT",
            "carrier": 59,
            "carrier_code": "DFFC",
            "carrier_name": "Dole"
        },
        "origin_transhipment_port_data": {
            "pk": 826,
            "unlocode": "NOAES",
            "name": "Aalesund Norway",
            "slug": "aalesund-norway",
            "short_name": "",
            "country": "Norway",
            "nearby": [],
            "tags": []
        },
        "main_service_data": {
            "pk": 1553,
            "name": "V SERVICE",
            "carrier": 2,
            "carrier_code": "ACLU",
            "carrier_name": "ACL-Atlantic Container Line"
        },
        "main_transhipment_port_data": {
            "pk": 1294,
            "unlocode": "EGAIC",
            "name": "Aict In El Dekheila Port",
            "slug": "aict-in-el-dekheila-port",
            "short_name": "",
            "country": "Egypt",
            "nearby": [],
            "tags": []
        },
        "destination_service_data": {
            "pk": 45,
            "name": "ACSA5",
            "carrier": 4,
            "carrier_code": "ANNU",
            "carrier_name": "ANL"
        }
    },
```

This is a sample of the object displayed on the row, as you can see I have more than 1 data in the sellers_data. What I wanted to do was filter the rows using that name.

I tried making the sellers_data.name into concatenated string for filtering but it did not work.

this is also what I have on the columns:

```html
  const columns = [
    {
        field: "pk",
        headerName: "ID",
        filterable: false,
    },
    {
        field: "sellers_data",
        headerName: "Sellers",
        renderCell: (params) => {
            // Create a string representation of seller names for filtering
            const sellersString = params.value.map((seller) => seller.name).join(', ');

            return (
                <Tooltip title={
                    <div>
                        {params.value.map((seller) => (
                            <Typography
                                key={seller.pk}
                                style={{
                                    color: colors.white[300],
                                    textDecoration: "none",
                                    display: 'block',
                                }}
                            >
                                {seller.name}
                            </Typography>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                }>
                    <Typography
                        style={{
                            color: colors.greenAccent[300],
                            textDecoration: "none",
                        }}
                    >
                        {/* {sellersString} */}
                        {params.value.length} Seller(s)
                    </Typography>
                </Tooltip>
            );
        },
    },
    {
        field: "full_name",
        headerName: "Transhipment Rule",
        flex: 1,
    },
];
```

Been working on this for days now, can't seem to find out any solutions. Thank you in advance for those who will response.